# Non-symmetric, positive semidefinite, invertible matrix positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let M be a quadratic, non-symmetric, invertible matrix that is positive semidefinite (i.e. x'Mx>=0 for all x). Is M positive definite (i.e. x'Mx>0 for all nonzero x)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working over the real field, no. Consider $M=\pmatrix{1&2\\ 0&1}$ for instance. $M+M^T=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&1}$ positive semidefinite but not positive definite because it is singular.

Comment: I even thought about this example in a different context. thanks.